# Switch.class not in android.jar

Tags: android

Android 3.2.  Attempting to use Switch (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html) in my project.  Switch.class is not found in android.jar, which is the only jar included in the Eclipse project by the Android plugin.  I can add platforms/android-13/data/layoutlib.jar to the build path and then the project will compile, but won't deploy to the device with some very long error about not including core jar files in your project.

What am I missing?

PS - other widgets, like Spinner ARE in android.jar.

Comment: Doh, yeah API 14 = Android 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch is introduced in Android 4.0. That's why it is not in android.jar. Change API level for the project to 14 (Android 4.0) to fix this.